# Where can I create directories that are visible to Windows Explorer and my application in Android?

Tags: android, filesystems, file-permissions, data-storage

I am developing an application that has the following requirement:

> When the device is connected to a computer via USB, the user should be
>   able to use Windows Explorer to drag files into and out of the
>   application directory.
>
> The application will consume some of these files and produces others
>   which should be able to be copied back to the computer.
>
> The target device does not have an external storage device (for
>   example an SD Card).
>
> The directories that the files will be stored in should be accessible
>   whilst the application is running.

I've looked into the data storage page in the android documentation, but none of the methods stated there seem to do what I require.

Alternatively, is there a way to select the computer when the application is running and 'send' files via USB to the computer? How about for 'receiving' files?

What is the best way to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: If there's no external storage card (SD card), there's no way to do this AFAIK. When the phone is attached to the computer via USB, the only way you can transfer files back and forth is by mounting the SD card so that Windows recognizes it. The internal storage isn't available for access.

Comment: In eclipse, with ADT(or via command line), you can browse the directories and push in or pull out the files either in SD card or in internal storage. However, it seems that the Android SDK doesn't provide such functions. You may do some research on the ADT tools.

Comment: @Huang I've used that functionality to push / pull files from the device, but I can't expect my end-users to have the android SDK installed on thier computer.

Answer (score 1):

> When the device is connected to a computer via USB, the user should be able to use Windows Explorer to drag files into and out of the application directory.

If "the application directory" refers to a spot on external storage, this is possible.

> The application will consume some of these files and produces others which should be able to be copied back to the computer.

If this is supposed to happen simultaneously, the device must be running Android 3.x or higher. Android 1.x and 2.x did not support simultaneous access to external storage.

> The target device does not have an external storage device (for example an SD Card).

It needs to have something designated as "external storage". That does not have to be *removable* storage. On Android 3.x and 4.x, it is usually just a part of on-board flash that was designated to be accessible as external storage. In Android terms, "external storage" means "can be accessed by a host computer using USB and by all applications on the device as well".

> The directories that the files will be stored in should be accessible whilst the application is running.

Again, this requires Android 3.x or higher. If this is a custom device, that most likely means you are going to need to use the recently-released Android 4.0 source code.

> Alternatively, is there a way to select the computer when the application is running and 'send' files via USB to the computer? How about for 'receiving' files?

No and no, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What your going to want to do is use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory. Even if there is no sd card, most android devices partition a part of the on board memory to be used as external storage.

Comment: Atleast that is the case with my Xoom, or if I do not have an SD card in my Droid X